# In Python, how can I call an instance method on a descriptor?

Tags: python, descriptor

Given a descriptor class `MyDescriptor` with an extra method `describe`, and a class that defines an attribute a using the descriptor, how can I call the method `describe` on `a`?

```
class MyClass(object):
    a = MyDescriptor()

    def dump(self):
        print a.describe()
```

When I create an instance of MyClass, set its attribute a to 42 and then call `dump()`, I get:

```
"AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'describe'".
```

I'd like to use the descriptor to carry some metadata about the way its **set** method was called. I need to find a way to ask the descriptor instance for that metadata.

Comment: `self.a.describe()`?  Note that because you're using a `class variable` all instances of `MyClass` will contain the _same_ instance of `MyDescriptor`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To access the descriptor object itself you need to call it using class's `__dict__` attribute.

```
def dump(self):
    print type(self).__dict__['a'].describe()
```

For more info on descriptors read [Descriptor HowTo Guide](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/descriptor.html).

**Demo:**

```
class MyDescriptor(object):

    def __get__(self, obj, type=None):
        return self._val

    def __set__(self, obj, val):
        self._val = val

    def describe(self):
        return 'inside describe'

class MyClass(object):

    a = MyDescriptor()

    def __init__(self):
        self.a = 42

    def dump(self):
        print 'Inside dump()'
        print self.a.describe()

    def dump2(self):
        print 'Inside dump2()'
        print type(self).__dict__['a'].describe()

MyClass().dump2()
print '-'*20
MyClass().dump()
```

**Output:**

```
Inside dump2()
inside describe
--------------------
Inside dump()

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\SO.PY", line 26, in <module>
    MyClass().dump()
  File "C:\Python27\SO.PY", line 19, in dump
    print self.a.describe()
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'describe'
```

Comment: This feels unnecessarily complicated to me.  Why `type(self).__dict__`?  `self.a` accesses the same property directly.

Comment: @g.d.d.c `self.a` will call the `__get__` method of the descriptor.

Comment: Note that if the descriptor returns itself when `__get__` is called with `instance` set to `None` (indicating that it is being looked up in the class, rather than in an instance), you can avoid digging in the class `__dict__` and just use `MyClass.a.describe()`.

Comment: @Blckknght But in this case `__get__` is returning an integer not the descriptor, so the code is fine as is.

Comment: Why not just `MyClass.a` instead of `type(self).__dict__['a']` ?

Comment: @Ben Because `MyClass.a` will call the `__get__` method too, with `obj` set as `None`.

Comment: @Aशwiniचhaudhary: Sure, in your example, `MyDescriptor` always returns an integer from `__get__`. However, many real world descriptors (like `property`) can't function normally when accessed via the class, rather than an instance, so they return themselves in that case. If the descriptor the questioner is using does that too, then `MyClass.a.describe()` will work, even though `self.a.describe()` doesn't.